# VXML audio tag didn't work

Tags: vxml

I have some troubles with my vxml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<vxml version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" xml:lang="fr-FR">
  <form id="welcome">
    <field name="choice">
      <prompt>
        Bienvenue au test Raccrocher. Que voulez-vous faire? Raccrocher Taper 1, Redire ce message Taper 2, ou Revenir au menu principal taper 3
      </prompt>
      <grammar mode="dtmf" version="1.0" root="top">
        <rule id="top"><one-of><item>1</item><item>2</item><item>3</item></one-of></rule>
      </grammar>
      <filled>
        <if cond="choice == '1'">
          <audio src="SOME_URL" />
          <exit />
        <elseif cond="choice == '2'" />
          <clear namelist="choice" />
        <elseif cond="choice == '3'" />
          <goto next="SOME_URL" />
        </if>
      </filled>
    </field>
  </form>

</vxml>
```

This is my code and i can't play my song and I don't know why.
I need your help !

Comment: I recommend adding some log commands in the filled area to see if the flow is correct. If it is, verify that the format of your audio file is supported by your platform. For example, most platforms don't support MP3s and only certain types of encodings within a WAV file.

Comment: What are you using in place of SOME_URL ? it is file path or http path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audio element must be inside a prompt element. See the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-voicexml20-20040316/#dml4.1.3).